# Mysql InnoDB engine in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, innodb

I am using laravel and laravel migration mechanism. I created tables and seted up foreign keys. But the tables are MyISSAM so no foreign keys are created. Where do I enable / configure this? (to change it to InnoDB and not in the mysql server).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can edit your /config/database.php file, search for *mysql* entry and change:

`'engine' => null,`

to

`'engine' => 'InnoDB',`

This saves you from adding `$table->engine = "InnoDB";` for each of your Schemas ;)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: The question is now, why Laravel allows to create foreign key in the migrations files using MyISAM. Using MySQL 5.7 (so with InnoDB as default), the `migrate` command still creates table with MyISAM, and my foreign keys are only indexes. Weird.

Comment: @VincentDecaux, Laravel has given all the developers the functionality to create the foreign keys via migration code. Suppose if Laravel doesn't allow this functionality and someone, who is using the InnoDB engine, needed it then obviously he'll have to write the query(ies) separately to add foreign key constraints. Which in result will double his/her work and time as well.

Answer (score 14):

Define engine like this

```
  Schema::create("models", function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set the engine inside [Schema\Table closure.](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#storage-engines)

Comment: Sadly, that link seems to be dead now.

Comment: Now the way to do this is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations) in *Connection & Storage Engine*

Answer (score 4):

Another approach (for whose that don't uses database.php) is to include on `.env` file:

`DB_ENGINE=InnoDB`

Remember to check if you have `'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', null),` on your database.php

Answer (score 4):

I found @ThomasLAURENT is the best solution but what about the existing tables I have in my database.

Working around.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class ConvertTablesIntoInnoDB extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $tables = [
            'users',
            'products',
        ];
        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            DB::statement('ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' ENGINE = InnoDB');
        }
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $tables = [
            'users',
            'products',
        ];
        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            DB::statement('ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' ENGINE = MyISAM');
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow us to convert all the tables and roll-back them when I need.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to update your Mysql to 5.5 or higher. The default storage engine for Mysql now is InoDB

*Before MySQL 5.5.5, MyISAM is the default storage engine. (The default was changed to InnoDB in MySQL 5.5.5.) MyISAM is based on the older (and no longer available) ISAM storage engine but has many useful extensions.*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Once done, you can easily map relationships within the entity classes via Laravel

Comment: If the tables exist, changing the version to get a different default will not cause the existing tables to change.  You need `ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB;` (for each `t`).

Answer (score 2):

```
Schema::create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->string('email');
});
```

Like document Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#storage-engines

P/s: Thanks @Nico Haase for reminding me to provide the link.

Comment: Is there any way for a global definition, such that it works for **all** tables? What's that `email` column used for?

Comment: @NicoHaase, that email column is just an example & to answer your question `Yes` you can define it globally. To do that go to `config/database.php` and under `mysql` key change `'engine' => null,` to `'engine' => 'InnoDB',`.

Comment: This looks like copy&paste from https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#storage-engines - if you already do this, you should at least provide a link

Answer (score 1):

Use InnoDb tables on the server side it's best way to success. Use [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). It easy in Workbench. And, if you want read the native [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for those that don't use database.php) is to include on the .env file: **DB_ENGINE=InnoDB**. Remember to check if you have **'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', null)** on your ***database.php***